# What happen when GetStream.Read is executed?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcplistener

I have the following code as part of TCP server

```
Private Sub StartTcpClient(ByVal client As TcpClient)

    Dim bytesRead As Integer
    Dim RxBuffer(1024) As Byte
    Dim RxDataStr As String = ""

    Dim BeginTime As Date = Date.Now
    Dim CurrentTime As Date
    Dim ElapsedTicks As Long = -1
    'Dim elapsedSpan As New TimeSpan(elapsedTicks)

    While True
        bytesRead = client.GetStream.Read(RxBuffer, 0, RxBuffer.Length)'What happen here?

        If bytesRead > 0 Or ElapsedTicks < 3 * 10000000.0 Then 'Espera hasta 3 segundos

            CurrentTime = Date.Now
            ElapsedTicks = CurrentTime.Ticks - BeginTime.Ticks
            'RxDataStr = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(RxBuffer, 0, bytesRead) 'Original
            RxDataStr += System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(RxBuffer, 0, bytesRead) 'UTF8

        Else
            client.Close()
            AckString = RxDataStr
            AckReady = True
            AckPending = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

I wonder about what happen when the line GetStream.Read is executed.
It goes away from my code and doesn't come back until some data is collected or an error happens or something else?

What I need to do is close the current connection if the time between the data arrivals is bigger than 3 seconds.

Comment: In general yes, `Stream.Read` is a blocking read. You may want to look into async/await to do asynchronous I/O.

Comment: I'm using a Thread, so I have no problem the GUI, but with this part of the Thread code. If I use an async/await asynchronous I/O the While Loop, in the code above, does not overrun the processor? I'm thinking in to change the ReceiveTimeout to 3000.

Comment: You have [ReadAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx) and [BeginRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to read from a stream in a loop until no more data is received, or a certain amount of time has passed since you started reading.

The call you use to do this [`Stream.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) is a blocking call. So if you don't receive any data, this **will block indefinitely**.

Because in your case, the the stream instance you have is a `NetworkStream`, you can specify its **[`ReadTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk6w7hs8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** property to prevent this. This causes the following behavior:

> If the read operation does not complete within the time specified by
>   this property, the read operation throws an `IOException`.

Thus, you will have to catch the `IOException` and check if it is due to a read timeout. Your code would then look like this:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics

// ... other stuff

Dim stream As Stream = client.GetStream
Dim maxTime As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
Dim elapsed As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
Dim done As Boolean = False

While Not done
    Dim timeout As Long = CLng((maxTime - elapsed.Elapsed).TotalMilliseconds))
    If (timeout > 0) Then
        stream.ReadTimeout = timeout
        Try
            bytesRead = stream.Read(RxBuffer, 0, RxBuffer.Length)
            If bytesRead > 0 Then 'Espera hasta 3 segundos
                RxDataStr += System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(RxBuffer, 0, bytesRead) 'UTF8
            Else
                done = True
            End If
        Catch ioEx As IOException
            If elapsed.Elapsed > maxTime Then
                done = True ' due to read timeout
            Else
                Throw ' not due to read timeout, rethrow
            End If
        End Try
    Else
        done = True
    End If
End While

client.Close()
AckString = RxDataStr
AckReady = True
AckPending = False
```

Since you are doing I/O, I would also recommend performing it as an asynchronous operation using async/await and [`Stream.ReadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193669(v=vs.110).aspx). In this case you should make all the methods in your call chain do async/await.

Comment: If the ReadTimeout finish it will generate an error or just return 0 or -1 to bytesRead? There's no major problem If no data received because the routine that waits AckReady will check the length or AckString to decide if have data to process or not.

Comment: @E_Blue It will throw an `IOException` when the read is timed out. I added a `Try ... Catch` block to handle this.